# Where I can I find Zentyal ? 

Tags: 10.10, squid

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 Maverick.  Does anyone know where I can find a version of Zentyal for it?

I heard that webmin is not available any more, and I had a problem with it, so I'm trying to change the webmin to Zentyal. 
The problem now is that I can only find the version for Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid).

I'm having a problem with connection speed, which is why I need Zentyal to help me configure squid to cache the webpage for faster loading.

Answer (score 2):

The packages in the Ubuntu repository (which are named ebox as that is the project former name) are outdated.

You should be using the packages from Zentyal PPA. Instructions at:  http://trac.zentyal.org/wiki/Documentation/Community/Installation/InstallationGuide .

Note, however, that so far packages are published for Ubuntu LTS releases only (8.04, 10.04, 12.04).